# Check valid (sub)domain with regex in bash

Tags: bash, regular-expression

The regex below is correct if I test it on regex test sites.
But the code below does not accept any input.
Everything I try is wrong.

```
   #!/bin/bash


    domainRegex="(?=^.{4,253}$)(^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)"


    while [ "$domain" = "" ]
    do
            echo "Please provide domain:"
            read domain
    done

    until [[ $domain =~ $domainRegex ]]
    do
            echo "Enter valid domain:"
            read domain
    done
```

Comment: can you rely on other regex features, from say, `grep` ?

Comment: You're using a Perl-like regular expression. Bash supports POSIX extended regular expressions. Use Perl instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda or `zsh -o rematchpcre`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using features from Perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE). Namely, `(?=...)` and `(?:...)` aren't part of standard extended regular expressions which Bash uses.

But it seems to me you're only using the former  `(?=^.{4,253}$)` to check the length of the string. If that's correct, it's easy to replace that with a direct test against the string length:

```
if [ "${#domain}" -lt 4 ] || [ "${#domain}" -gt 253 ]; then
    echo "Domain name is too short or too long"
fi
```

Then, `(?:...)` is easy, it's the equivalent of `(...)`, except it doesn't capture. The extra captures don't matter in what the regex as a whole matches, so we can just drop the `?:` from each opening parenthesis.

Also note that (at least in ERE) the backslash in `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]` matches a *literal* backslash. A dash can be matched by just putting it as the first or last character in the bracket group (in both PCRE and ERE): `[a-zA-Z0-9-]`.

With those modifications, we get:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9](([a-zA-Z0-9-]){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/170373)

Comment: I didn't test that resulting regex too closely, though

Comment: Generally, you can't use ranges in EREs for input validation unless you switch to the C locale. `[a-z]` matches thousands of characters depending on locale or systems and may even match sequences of several characters. For instance, in Hungarian locales on GNU systems, `[[ dDZS =~ ^[a-z]$ ]]` returns true. As `dDZS` is a collating element that sorts in  between `a` and `z`.