# Using Bash "=~" operator with WHILE instead of UNTIL loop

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, testing

I'm writing some shell script which asks the user for a domain name. I'd like to prompt the user for input in a loop, and write an error message, if the input is not a valid domain name.

Basically, the code shall look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
read -p "Enter domain name: " DOMAIN_NAME

while [[ testing for valid domain name goes here ]]
do
  echo ''
  echo 'You entered an invalid domain name. Please re-enter.'
  echo '... more error message data ....'
  echo ''
  read -p "Enter domain name: " DOMAIN_NAME
done

echo "You entered domain name: $DOMAIN_NAME"
```

I've found some examples that show how the "=~" operator can be used to test against a reqular expression. However, the examples all show `UNTIL` loops. Using the regex from the answer to question [Check valid (sub)domain with regex in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548543/check-valid-subdomain-with-regex-in-bash), an example is:

```
# !/bin/bash

until [[ "$DOMAIN_NAME" =~ ^([a-zA-Z0-9](([a-zA-Z0-9-]){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$ ]]
do
  read -p "Enter domain name: " DOMAIN_NAME
done

echo "You entered domain name: $DOMAIN_NAME"
```

While this works, it is not straitforward to write an additional error message in case the user entered invalid data. Such a message would have to be written inside the loop, before the `read`, but not on first iteration.

For this reason I'd rather write the loop as a `while` loop as shown above. I'm unable to find how I can negate the test expresssion, which is needed when rewriting the `until` loop as a `while` loop.

Comment: `until ! [[ $foo =~ bar ]]`

Comment: So simple, of course! From reading examples, such as `[^a-z]` which matches any character *except* from a-z, I was blinded and searched for the negation of the regular expression. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`until cmd` is the same as `while ! cmd`.

Here, just do:

```
until
  IFS= read -rep 'Enter domain name: ' domain
  [[ $domain =~ $regexp ]]
do
  printf>&2 'Invalid domain: "%s"\n' "$domain"
done

printf 'You entered: "%s"\n' "$domain"
```

Same as:

```
while
  IFS= read -rep 'Enter domain name: ' domain
  ! [[ $domain =~ $regexp ]]
do
  printf>&2 'Invalid domain: "%s"\n' "$domain"
done

printf 'You entered: "%s"\n' "$domain"
```

Or:

```
while
  IFS= read -rep 'Enter domain name: ' domain
  [[ ! $domain =~ $regexp ]]
do
  printf>&2 'Invalid domain: "%s"\n' "$domain"
done

printf 'You entered: "%s"\n' "$domain"
```

Note that we have the `read` in the condition part of the `while`/`until` loop so it's run each time before the regexp test, but we don't check its exit status. It's the last command run in the condition part (here `[[ ... ]]` or `! [[ ... ]]`) that determines the branching of the loop.

Also remember you can't use character ranges for input validation unless you fix the locale to C or switch to a shell like zsh where ranges are based on code points.

```
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
until
  domain=
  vared -p 'Enter domain name: ' domain
  [[ $domain = ([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-](#c0,61)[a-zA-Z0-9]|).)##[a-zA-Z](#c2,5) ]]
do
  printf>&2 'Invalid domain: "%s"\n' "$domain"
done
printf 'You entered: "%s"\n' "$domain"
```

(here using the `vared` (var editor) builtin to be able to use zsh's line editor like bash's `read -e`).

If using `=~` to do regexp matching in `zsh` (as opposed to glob pattern matching with `=`), you'd want to make sure you use PCREs by using the `rematchpcre` option. By default, you get EREs like in bash with all its limitations. But remember that PCRE's equivalent of ERE's `$` is `\z`. So:

```
regexp='^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,5}\z'
```

Beware that in UTF-8 locales, sequences of bytes not forming valid characters would trigger PCRE errors. Those are handled more gracefully when using zsh glob patterns.

In bash, outside the C locale, you need `[0123456789]` instead of `[0-9]` if you want to match on only those 10 characters (with or without the `globasciiranges` option enabled). Same for `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]`. At least in bash, variables can't contain the NUL byte, so you don't have to worry about regexps not being able to match on those.

Also remember:

- using `read` without `-r` and without `IFS=` hardly ever makes sense in bash.
- `echo` shouldn't be used to output arbitrary data.
- errors should go to stderr

Comment: Thanks for the examples showing multiple command in the contition part. Didn't know that.